# Extract complex data from XML using pySpark RDD

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an XML file with this data:

```
<Products>
  <ID="tr_123" newID="user">
    <Name>Some Name</Name>
      <ClassReference ClassID="m8" Type="Pro"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="Year_1998" Type="app_to_year"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="in_30" Type="app_to_in"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="lier_6" Type="plier"/>

    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="ber">7701</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="key">V61</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="g_key">30_70_1991</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="create_date">2-01-21</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="user">SYS</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="pc_quantity">1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="mode" Derived="true">Save</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="link" Derived="true">t (755234)</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="app_date" Derived="true">20-11-99</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="year" Derived="true">1777</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="ink" Derived="true">CID</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="make" Derived="true">CMC</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="calcu" Derived="true">1 198 na 25/ Tn</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>

  <ID="tr_1234" newID="user1">
    <Name>Some Name1</Name>
      <ClassReference ClassID="m81" Type="Pro"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="Year_1988" Type="app_to_year"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="in_302" Type="app_to_in"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="lier_61" Type="plier"/>
      <ClassReference ClassID="lier_Die" Type="NOW"/>
    <MetaData>
        <Value AttributeID="t_seq_num">999</Value>
    </MetaData>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="ber">71</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="key">V6d1</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="g_key">30_780_1991</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="create_date">2-09-21</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="user">SYS</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="pc_quantity">21</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="mode" Derived="true">Shave</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="link" Derived="true">t (7553234)</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="app_date" Derived="true">20-11-939</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="year" Derived="true">17774</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="ink" Derived="true">CIDid</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="make" Derived="true">CMerC</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="calcu" Derived="true">1 198 na 2w5/ Tn</Value>
      <Value AttributeID="die" Derived="true">now</Value>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

this is just a small part.

I am trying to get the following data:

**ID, newID, Name ,**
**all the Values with AttributeID data as column name and the value in the row**

and

**all the data from ClassReference with type as column name and ClassID as row**

*ex: output for First ID tag will be*

```
ID,newID,Name,Pro,app_to_year,app_to_in,plier,ber,key,g_key,create_date,user,pc_quantity,mode,link,app_date,year,ink,make,calcu
tr_123,user,Some Name,m8,Year_1998,in_30,lier_6,7701,V61,30_70_1991,02/01/21,SYS,1,Save,t (755234),20-11-99,1777,CID,CMC,1 198 na 25/ Tn
```

the above data is in CSV formate.

But this is only for **ID tag tr_123** the first one .In the second one we have more Value tags and ClassReference hense hear lay my problem.
I want all the data, so for the data missing in first ID Tag I want those columns to have Null

ex :The above df will become

```
ID,newID,Name,Pro,app_to_year,app_to_in,plier,ber,key,g_key,create_date,user,pc_quantity,mode,link,app_date,year,ink,make,calcu,t_seq_num,lier_Die,die
tr_123,user,Some Name,m8,Year_1998,in_30,lier_6,7701,V61,30_70_1991,02/01/21,SYS,1,Save,t (755234),20-11-99,1777,CID,CMC,1 198 na 25/ Tn,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

If I use spark-xml to solve this problem the code is becoming very complex and slow.

So is their a way to do it using RDD and and if so can some one give me any Idea as to what and where do i have to go.
I have very little experience working with RDD, So any help is welcomed.

***And If Not RDD then what other things I can try. I am dealing with very big Files so Pandas and all wont work.***

Comment: Hi Andy, so what solution have you tried so far and it was slow?

Comment: Hi i tried using dataframe approch but as i said that was not very good.

Comment: Right now i am reading the xml as txt in rdd and then split the data based  on Product  ,then for each part i am spliting based on values.I will update my code soon . right now i am stuck at a bug.

Comment: never mind i solved it ..:-)